# Windows 10 language bar hot keys get forgotten after logout

Tags: windows-10, language

If you go to `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings`and click on  `Change language bar hot keys` then you can define hot keys for input languages. My problem is it works till I logout or do a restart then I have to set it again. Is this a known bug? Did I miss something?
It is a Windows 10 Home x86 v1511 OS Build 10586.318 running on a Lenovo MIIX 300-10IBY tablet.

Comment: You can try to hit **Windows Key** + **Space** continually till the desired language is selected.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but a program would rely on the hotkey so it is not acceptable way.

Comment: Try deleting the contents of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\Hot Keys` -> Restart -> Configure HotKeys again. Remember to take a backup of registry before attempting anything.

Comment: Did not work :(

Comment: Check it this is your case: https://superuser.com/a/1134363/197742

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I cannot test your solution since I don't have the afformentioned tablet anymore. Although it seems pretty the same problem so maybe it can be a duplicate.

Comment: FWIW this is happening to me too.